# Disable div depending of variable razor with ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, server-side-validation

I need disable a div depending of a variable razor.
I tried a css class but not working because it is very simple disable with developer tools.
there is a safe method to perform this task.?
I use ASP.NET MVC 4.0

```
 .disableddiv {
pointer-events: none;
opacity: 0.4;
```

}

regards

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: what do you mean by disable a div ? is it editable ? do you want to disable it's children ? Please post the view content

Comment: show us the code snippet you have tried

Comment: I use a css class for disable un div, but it is very simple to reenable through development tools browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
 @if (variable) { 
    <div>

    </div>
 }
```

Where `variable` is the variable that dictates if the div appears (like `showDiv == true`, for example) and div is the div you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="@(Model.booleanVariable ? "disabled=disabled" : "disabled=''")">Some links</div>
```